# Safely store Twitter Oauth tokens, public Github repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, twitter

In my Rails app I want to use the [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) for accessing the Twitter API. I'm storing the OAuth secrets in a file under `config/initializers/twitter.rb` Since I want to put the code in a public repository on Github my first reaction was to incude the file in `gitignore`. However, this solution does not work with hosting on Heroku, which requires a git repository that includes the secrets.

Comment: Did you consider using environment variables?

Comment: not yet, I will look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the OAuth secrets from environment variables using something like Dotenv  (https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) would allow you to set and use them locally and in Heroku without having to store them in a file. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars for setting env variables in Heroku.